# QuickGraph - How can I associate an Edge with a Class? (i.e. like you can with a Vertex)

Tags: quickgraph

Q1 - How can I associate an Edge with a Class?  (i.e. like you can with a Vertex)

In my case there are various types of edges I want to be able to model.  So my real question I guess is how can I associate some level of data with Edges (e.g. edge type).

The graph I was looking at using was:  http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BidirectionalGraph&referringTitle=Documentation

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An edge by default only connects two vertices on the graph.  If you need more information associated with an edge (i.e. a "Relationship"), you can implement the `IEdge<T>` interfaces or subclass `Edge<T>`.  Then, in your custom edge class you can store the information that's relevant to that edge.

i.e.

```
public class MyEdge<TVertex> : Edge<TVertex>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public MyEdge(TVertex source, TVertex target) : base(source, target)
    {
    }
}
```

... later

```
var graph = new BidirectionalGraph<int, MyEdge<int>>();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the TaggedEdge class, which allows you to associate an arbitrary object with each edge.